# Determine and classify all critical points of function.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Determine and classify all critical points of function :
$$G(x,y)=4x^2 + 9y^2 - x^2 y^2 +1$$

I have:
$$G'_x=8x-2xy^2$$
& 
$$G'_y=18y-2x^2y$$

Have a feeling this is wrong so i cant continue the question. I understand in order to find you must first find derivative with respect to x and then y and make both equal to zero and then solve for x and y to get critical points.

Comment: Seems to me you are on track and can keep going looking for roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. In case you are hesitating just because you can't sovle the equations, these might help.

$$8x-2xy^2=2x(4-y^2)=0$$

$$18y-2x^2y=2y(9-x^2)=0$$

You should have $5$ solutions.

Comment: how would there be 5 solutions ? i have x=0, x=4 & y=0 , y = 9 ?

Comment: How did you get $x=4$? you should state your solution in a pair $(x,y)$, for example, $(0, 0)$ is a solution.

Comment: apoligies that should be  x=0 , x= 2 & y=0, y= 9 , so (0,0)= P1  and (2,9) P2 . is this correct ?

Comment: $(4,2)$ is not a solution since $2y(9-x^2)=2(2)(9-4^2) \neq 0$.

Comment: If $y=2$, what are the possible values for $x$?

Comment: X would equal to 3

Comment: If $y=2$, the first equation is satisfied. For the second equation, it reduces to $9-x^2=0$, hence $x = \pm 3$. Is it possible that $y=-2$?, if so, what are the corresponding values of $x$?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct!

Just continue by setting $$8x-2xy^2=18y-2x^2y=0$$

and solving for $x$ and $y$.

Edit:

$x(4-y^2)=0\implies x=0\quad\text{or}\quad y=\pm2$

$x=0\implies 18y=0\implies y=0$

$y=\pm 2\implies 18\cdot \pm2-2x^2\cdot\pm2=0\implies\pm36\mp4x^2=0\implies \pm x^2=\pm9\implies x=\pm3$

Then the solutions are $(x,y)= (0,0)\quad\text{or}\quad(-3,2)\quad\text{or}\quad(-3,-2)\quad\text{or}\quad(3,2)\quad\text{or}\quad(3,-2)$

Comment: @user3806399 I adjusted my answer, those solutions should be presented in pairs. Do you follow it now?

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that (0, 0), (3, 2), (3, -2), (-3, 2) and (-3, -2) are the only critical points.
2. Define a 2x2 Hessian matrix H as the matrix consisting of second derivative of f wrt x and y. Compute  $h_{11}$ and delta = det H. Evaluate H at each critical point.
3. Verify that the Hessian is positive definite (delta >0 and $h_{11}$ > 0)  @(0, 0), hence it is a local minimum.
4. Verify that the delta < 0 at the rest of the critical points. Hence the remaining points are inconclusive.  We need to evaluate higher order derivative to reach a conclusion.